# How do I make a list of objects parcelable in Android?

Tags: android, parcelable

So I have an app that searches for an artist on the internet, via an API and displays the list of the results (artist names) after performing this search at hand. I want to retain this list as I change the orientation (portrait - landscape) of my device and not having to perform the search again. Here is some code:

```
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment{

    public static final String ARTIST_ID = "artistId";
    private final String NO_RESULTS = "No artists found. Please check your input!";

    private List<Artist> artists = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArtistArrayAdapter adapter;

    public MainActivityFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.search_artist);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String artistName) {
                SearchArtist(artistName);
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(searchView.getWindowToken(), 0);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                return false;
            }
        });

        ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        adapter = new ArtistArrayAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.artist_list_item, artists);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Artist artist = artists.get(position);
                String artistId = artist.id;
                Intent detailArtist = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailActivity.class);
                detailArtist.putExtra(ARTIST_ID, artistId);
                startActivity(detailArtist);
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }
```

So I think I have to make the List of artists parcelable and then pass it to the onSaveInstanceState method. But how do make this list parcelable?

Thanks a lot, I hope this isn't too confusing...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll need to implement the Parcelable Interface for your Artist Data Model class. For example

```
public class ArtistParcelable implements Parcelable {
    public String id;
    public String artistName;
    public List<String> artistImageUrls = Collections.emptyList();

    public ArtistParcelable(Artist artist) {
        // Do the assignments here
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        //write 
        dest.writeString(this.id);
        dest.writeString(this.artistName);
        dest.writeStringList(this.artistImageUrls);
    }

    protected ArtistParcelable(Parcel in) {
        //retrieve
        this.id = in.readString();
        this.artistName = in.readString();
        this.artistImageUrls = in.createStringArrayList();
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<ArtistParcelable> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<ArtistParcelable>() {
        public ArtistParcelable createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new ArtistParcelable(source);
        }

        public ArtistParcelable[] newArray(int size) {
            return new ArtistParcelable[size];
        }
    };
}
```

And in your fragment - if you have List mArtists, then you save and retrieve the list like

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(final Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putParcelableArrayList(ARTISTS, (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) mArtists);
}
```

And in onCreateView

```
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mArtists = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList(ARTISTS);
```

Here's a good guide, which you can follow. 
https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-Parcelable

There's an IDE plugin called [Android Parcelable Code Generator](https://github.com/mcharmas/android-parcelable-intellij-plugin) available also, which generates all the boilerplate code for you.

And there's also a library called [Parceler](https://github.com/johncarl81/parceler), which is pretty handy. It removes the boilerplate entirely.

Comment: It's not necessary, because if I'm not wrong then you'd be getting the base Artist class objects from the API, so even if you create your Parcelable as a sub-class of Artist, you'll still need to convert your Artist object into an ArtistParcelable one.

Answer (score 0):

First your Artist class must implement parcelable

```
public class Artist implements Parcelable
```

Then you should override the method writeToParcel saying what you want to save, for example:

```
  @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
            dest.writeString(mSavedString);
     }
```

create a constructor to read the saved variables:

```
 protected Artist(Parcel in){
    mSavedString = in.readString();
}
```

Then the creator:

```
 public static final Parcelable.Creator<Artist> CREATOR
             = new Parcelable.Creator<Artist>() {
         public Artist createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
             return new Artist(in);
         }

         public Artist[] newArray(int size) {
             return new Artist[size];
         }
     };
```

And finally on your activity override onsavedinstance:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putParcelableArray("AristArray", mArtistArray);
}
```

Also, do not forget to retrive by doing this onCreate of your activity:

```
 if (savedInstanceState != null) {
   mArtistArray= new List<Artist>(savedInstanceState.getParcelableArray("ArtistArray"));
 }
```

Ps: did not try the code, so anything you want to know ask, I will try and help you ;)

src: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html

Hope it help ;)

Answer (score 0):

How About modifying your Artist class to make it Parcelabel.

```
public class Artist implements Parcelable {

    public static final Creator<Artist> CREATOR = new Creator<Artist>() {
        public Artist createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new Artist(source);
        }

        public Artist[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Artist[size];
        }
    };

    private final String name;

    public Artist(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    private Artist(Parcel in) {
        name = in.readString();
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(name);
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Then use following.

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
 outState.putParcelableArrayList("key_artists",artists);
}
```